# Download by SFTP and save file to different directory

Tags: python, ftp, sftp

I would like to know how to save download file to different directory. I test using code below advise from member here. I tried by defined localpath but got error.

Code

```
with pysftp.Connection(host=myHostname, username=myUsername, password=myPassword, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    with sftp.cd('/home/operation/genfiles'):             
        files = []
        localpath = '/home/mylocalDir'
        for filename in sftp.listdir():
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, "filegen_*.json"): 
                files.append(filename)
        latestFile = max(listFile)
        sftp.get(latestFile, localpath)
```

Error when executed the code above. Its a directory where the latestFile should be saved.

```
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/mylocalDir'
```

Pls help and appreciate advise. Thank you

Comment: `localpath = '/home/mylocalDir'` You need to specify the filename in it to save to the localDir. `localDir/file1.txt`

Comment: Hi sir. the files that I download from remote server have their own file names ...so if I specify filename in localdir ...would it be any problem? What I'm thinking is what ever files download from remote server will be save to my local directory. Thus local dir will have multiple files.

Comment: You are downloading one specific file. It is irrelevant what files are in the local folder already.